# Being asked to write your new job description: can it be used against you?

Tags: team-role

I recently changed department in a software company.
I did a bit of everything, but in this team roles are more defined.
I expected to be told: "this is your box, you either fit or I can find somebody else who does".

Instead, my new manager wants me to write my own job description, based on what I enjoy doing and what I do best.
It sounds too good to be true.

Where is the catch? Can something like "your own job description" be used against me, and how?

Comment: vtc - primarily opinion based and very broad. But to the OP - why wouldn't you just talk to your manager about this? they seem pretty open and are trying to create a collaborative air. I'd actually love it if you updated your question as to *why* you aren't asking your manager - just so managers get an idea of what a team member thinks in times like this. Also, sounds like you have a good manager.

Comment: The "catch" is that someone will need to approve it.

Comment: This will depend on your manager...

Comment: I've been asked to write my job description many times over the years. It's a common practice because bosses often don't understand exactly what you do. My last boss was a Java programmer who knew nothing of front-end. So I wrote my own description. They're asking you to help communicate with co-workers what you do. So they know who in the office has knowledge of such things.

Comment: mandatory reference http://dilbert.com/strip/2018-06-10

Comment: `my new manager wants me to write my own job description, based on what I enjoy doing and what I do best` would it be less confusing for you if your manager had asked you to `write your own PREFERRED job description, based on what you enjoy doing and what you do best`? I get the feeling that that's what they intended but failed to communicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Where is the catch? Can something like "your own job description" be used against me, and how?

Hard to tell without more context, but **I don't see why this is necessarily a trap.**

Your manager may be asking you to write this yourself so it is *phrased in a more realistic perspective* (as you are the one who knows what you really do), so they can use such phrasing in the public profile of your company, or similar. Perhaps other coworkers have been asked to do the same so all descriptions are in the perspective of the employee.

He could also be doing this to help you get *immersed on your new position*, as a way of you to define and be conscious of your new roles, so you can then mindfully carry on with your tasks (as in a way for you to research a bit and "own" your new job).

Have in mind that **writing your own job description is different than determining what tasks you will be doing in that job**, so sadly don't think that if you write *"wild wolf trainer"* you will be actually doing so.

This seems more like a "funny" dynamic that your manager came up with, so I suggest that you carry out and ask him if you got any more doubts about what this description will be used for.

Comment: I wanna be a wild wolf trainer....

Comment: @Neo sorry, we are not hiring at the moment...

Comment: @Neo https://youtu.be/-8I5TtNfjBI?t=1m43s

Comment: @cgTag Or a Lion Tamer!!!

Comment: @Neo you can do anything if you have the right hat!